# How to save an excel file with all macros and formulas in the new workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

HI I have made a bit complex macro file and I am trying to split and save the files for each filter and then hide the sheets and lock everything apart from two ranges in two different sheets!

The code:

```
 Sub ExportXLSM()
    
 Dim myWorksheets() As String 'Array to hold worksheet names to copy
 Dim newWB As Workbook
 Dim CurrWB As Workbook
 Dim sht As Worksheet
 Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range
 Dim r As Long

 Set CurrWB = ThisWorkbook

 Dim userpath As String
 userpath = Environ("UserProfile")
    
 Dim sToday As String
 Dim s11 As Worksheet
 Set s11 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Monthly_Budget")
    
 Dim MyPath As String
 Dim MyFileName As String

 sToday = s11.Range("A7").Value

 myWorksheets = Split("Summary, Monthly_Budget, History_1, Copy2", ",")

 MyFileName = "KIG_BUDGET_2024_" & sToday & ".xlsm"

 With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Select the location and click ok!"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = userpath & "\Desktop\" ' removed spaces
    If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub 'Exit if no folder is selected
    MyPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
 End With

 Set newWB = Workbooks.Add 'Create new workbook

 Dim i As Integer
 For i = LBound(myWorksheets) To UBound(myWorksheets)
     Set sht = CurrWB.Sheets(Trim(myWorksheets(i)))
     Set rng = sht.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
     
     newWB.Sheets.Add(After:=newWB.Sheets(newWB.Sheets.Count)).Name = Trim(myWorksheets(i))
     
     For Each rng2 In rng.Areas
         r = newWB.Sheets(Trim(myWorksheets(i))).Cells(newWB.Sheets(Trim(myWorksheets(i))).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
         rng2.Copy Destination:=newWB.Sheets(Trim(myWorksheets(i))).Cells(r, 1)
     Next rng2
     Cells.Select
     Selection.Columns.AutoFit
 Next i


 newWB.SaveAs Filename:=MyPath & MyFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
 newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Delete 
 newWB.Close saveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

1. My VBA codes and macro are not there in the new file, I want to copy the exact same formulas in the file, not taking ref from the parent file!
2. It is taking the filtered data but not the header which has filters.

My aim in the end to copy the whole file for filtered data, hide some sheets, Sheet2 for example and lock all the cells except two ranges one in Summary and one in Monthly Budget

Comment: If you want to use most of the current workbook (incl. VBA, formulars, etc), I guess the easiest approach would be to save a copy with `CurrWB.SaveCopyAs(filename, other options)` and then open the copy as new Workbook with `Set newWb = Workbooks.Open(filename)`. Then you can apply the desired changes in the new workbook.

Comment: @slarag beat me to it by seconds - that is exactly the right approach.
There are ways of manipulating the VBA project but they are not robust and should be avoided imho

Comment: The above suggested solution looks more appropriate. But there are some strange approaches in your actual code: 1. In order to not use `Trim` anymore, split by `", "` instead of `","`. 2. Iterating between areas and copy each area your code only consumes more time. If you paste all the range at once you will obtain the same result. But if you would try using 2D formula arrays instead of copying, the code will be faster and keeps the sheet (name) references.  I mean, `newWB.Sheets(myWorksheets(i)).Cells(r, 1).Formula = rng2.Formula`. Then, you must say what macros from which module to copy...

Comment: I tried can you please tell me how to copy paste formulas
After rng.Copy or Instead? Sorry I am new